# When I use a while loop in my rock paper scissors code, it repeats itself

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am trying to make a rock paper scissors code that requires two people to play, however when I try to use a `while` loop, it continually prints the answer.

The code:

```
play = input("Do you want to play?")
player1 = input("Rock, paper or scissors?")
player2 = input("Rock, paper or scissors?")
while play == "no":
    print("Why are you wasting my time? HUH?")
while play == "yes":

    if (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'scissors'):
        print ("Player 1 wins.")
    elif (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'rock'):
        print ("Tie")
    elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'paper'):
        print ("Player 1 wins.")
    elif (player2 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'scissors'):
        print ("Tie")
    elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'paper'):
        print ("Tie")
    elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'scissors'):
        print ("Player 2 wins.")
    elif (player1 == 'rock'and player2 == 'paper'):
        print ("Player 2 wins.")
    elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'rock'):
        print ("Player 2 wins.")
    elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'rock'):
        print ("Player 2 wins.")     
    else:
        print ("This is not a valid object selection.")
```

Comment: Well thats what `while` does...

Comment: And what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: it wont stop repeating, and I wanted to make it ask again after the game has finished so you have the option to play again.

Comment: Think about when `play` might actually get updated...

Comment: Well reading the input INSIDE the loop could help.

Comment: Python reads a lot like English.  You said "while play is equal to 'no', print 'Why are you wasting my time?'".  In other words, it will keep printing until play is not equal to 'no'.  Since you nowhere in that loop told it to equal something else, it will keep printing forever.  Similarly, your other loop never sets play to be anything other than 'yes', so it will keep printing its message forever.  Just think about it like English, and it should be easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `play` never changes, after you entered either loop. Hence the loop repeats forever. You must move the `input` into the loop as well.

I reworked the code a bit using only one while loop, as that is easier to do, which is canceled using `break`, if the player wants to stop playing. Otherwise both players are asked for their move and then the according output is printed. After that the while loop repeats the whole thing.

I also added a the else-case to the if statement in case neither yes nor no is answered when asked whether they want to play. Then I just print an error message and then looping again.

```
while True:
    play = input("Do you want to play?")
    if play == "no":
        print("Why are you wasting my time? HUH?")
        break # exits the loop if you don't want to play
    elif play == "yes":
        player1 = input("Rock, paper or scissors?")
        player2 = input("Rock, paper or scissors?")
        if (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'scissors'):
            print ("Player 1 wins.")
        elif (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'rock'):
            print ("Tie")
        elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'paper'):
            print ("Player 1 wins.")
        elif (player2 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'scissors'):
            print ("Tie")
        elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'paper'):
            print ("Tie")
        elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'scissors'):
            print ("Player 2 wins.")
        elif (player1 == 'rock'and player2 == 'paper'):
            print ("Player 2 wins.")
        elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'rock'):
            print ("Player 2 wins.")
        elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'rock'):
            print ("Player 2 wins.")     
        else:
            print ("This is not a valid object selection.")
    else:
        print("What?")
```

Answer (score 1):

`while` will repeat whatever is inside the loop until you give a break condition. In your case, you may want to replace the two `while` loops with `if` conditions, so it doesn't spam your command line.

If you want it to automatically ask for another game afterwards, you can just make a method out of your game and prompt another user input asking for another game yes/no.

```
def game():
        if (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'scissors'):
            print ("Player 1 wins.")
        elif (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'rock'):
            print ("Tie")
        elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'paper'):
            print ("Player 1 wins.")
        elif (player2 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'scissors'):
            print ("Tie")
        elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'paper'):
            print ("Tie")
        elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'scissors'):
            print ("Player 2 wins.")
        elif (player1 == 'rock'and player2 == 'paper'):
            print ("Player 2 wins.")
        elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'rock'):
            print ("Player 2 wins.")
        elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'rock'):
            print ("Player 2 wins.")
        else:
            print ("This is not a valid object selection.")

play = input("Do you want to play?")
player1 = input("Rock, paper or scissors?")
player2 = input("Rock, paper or scissors?")
if play == "no":
    print("Why are you wasting my time? HUH?")
elif play == "yes":
    game()
    another = input("Want to play again?")
    if another == "yes":
        game()
    else:
        print("Okay bye then.")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, it really helped :)